# different view size in SpriteKit for iphone 6 plus

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, iphone-6-plus

I am running two different SpriteKit games in 6plus simulator and printing the following line in its ViewController :

```
NSLog(@"size = %@",NSStringFromCGSize(self.view.bounds.size));
```

The same simulator returns:
`size = {414, 736}` in one of the games, while the other returns: `size = {320, 568}`

How is this possible?

Comment: Are you using `LaunchScreen` or add proper Launch images for iPhone 6+?

Comment: both game complied with same iOS version just check it out ?

Comment: @Bannings the problem is not the launch image, but the whole scene not resizing.

Comment: Both games compiled with target 7.1

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved: The fix for this was to delete the LaunchScreen.xib file and remove the "launch screen" from general settings.